# Is it possible to write a Sqoop incremental import with filters on the new file before importing?

Tags: hadoop, merge, hdfs, sqoop

My doubt is, Say, I have a file A1.csv with 2000 records on sql-server table, I import this data into hdfs, later that day I have added 3000 records to the same file on sql-server table. 
Now, I want to run incremental import for the second chunk of data to be added on hdfs, but, I do not want complete 3000 records to be imported. I need only some data according to my necessity to be imported, like, 1000 records with certain condition to be imported as part of the increment import.

Is there a way to do that using sqoop incremental import command?

Please Help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a unique key or a Timestamp field to identify the deltas which is the new 1000 records in your case. using that field you have to options to bring in the data to Hadoop.

---

**Option 1**

is to use the sqoop incremental append, below is the example of it

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@enkx3-scan:1521:dbm2 \
--username wzhou \
--password wzhou \
--table STUDENT \
--incremental append \
--check-column student_id \
-m 4 \
--split-by major
```

Arguments :

```
--check-column (col)  #Specifies the column to be examined when determining which rows to import.

--incremental (mode)      #Specifies how Sqoop determines which rows are new. Legal values for mode include append and lastmodified.

--last-value (value) Specifies the maximum value of the check column from the previous import.
```

---

**Option 2**

Using the `--query` argument in sqoop where you can use the native sql for mysql/any database you connect to.

Example :

```
sqoop import \
  --query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
  --split-by a.id --target-dir /user/foo/joinresults

sqoop import \
  --query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
  -m 1 --target-dir /user/foo/joinresults
```

Comment: So, Using querying(option 2) we can choose if we want whole of 3000 records or only selective 1000 from them?

Comment: You can change your query to how ever you want, 1000 or 2000 rows.. if you want all the records just select * without any conditions.