# Dynamic spool space allocation in teradata

Tags: hdfs, teradata, sqoop

I have huge data and am importing it from teradata to hdfs. While doing so, usually spool space is insufficient and the job thus fails. Is there any solution for this? Can spool space be allocated dynamically as per data size? Or can we load the data from sqoop import into a temporary buffer and then write it to hdfs?

Comment: Increase the mappers in sqoop to have good # splits, that might help you by increasing mappers and using index field in split-by can add a lot of advantage. Here is my answer on how you can leverage split-by and mappers combination: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556141/is-it-possible-to-write-a-sqoop-incremental-import-with-filters-on-the-new-file/48572585#48572585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running out of SPOOL, it could be any of these scenarios:

1. Incorrectly written query (i.e. unintended CROSS JOIN)

   Do an EXPLAIN on your query and check for a product join or anything that looks like it will take a long time
2. Inefficient query plan

   Run an EXPLAIN and see if there are any long estimates.  Also, you can try `DIAGNOSTIC HELPSTATS ON FOR SESSION`.  When you enable this flag, any time you run an EXPLAIN, at the bottom you will get a bunch of recommended statistics to collect.  Some of these suggestions may be useful
3. Tons of data

   Not much you can do here.  Maybe try to do the import in batches.

Also, you can check to see what the MaxSpool parameter is for the user running the query.  You could try to increase the MaxSpool value to see if that helps.  Keep in mind, the actual spool available will be capped by the amount of unallocated PERM space.

Comment: 4) high data skew. With highly uneven distributed data you may run out of spool on one amp, while the overall MaxSpool should be sufficient.

Comment: I'll try out the options mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, Ulick has a good point...it's probably #4.  Check your source TD table to see if the table data is evenly distributed -- you can use TD's built-in HASH (`hashamp/hashbucket/hashrow`) functions to calculate this.  Also, do an EXPLAIN to see if your query has any aggregation/re-distribution steps on potentially unevenly distributed data

Comment: I think #4 is the problem with my data. I'll try some workarounds!